# Parallel execution of tests in testNG Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am not able to invoke the browsers in  parallel, which are currently invoking one after another. Need a way to invoke the browsers in parallel tests.
NOTE: In my configuration xml file I have kept the thread count as 2.

Below is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"; > 
<suite name="Parallel" parallel="tests" thread-count="4" > 
    <test verbose="3" name="<name>"> 
        <parameter name="platform" value ="win8"/> 
        <parameter name="browsername" value ="internet explorer"/> 
        <classes> 
            <class name="com.parallel.execution.ParallelExecution"> 
                <methods> 
                    <include name="testmethod1"/> 
                </methods> 
             </class> 
         </classes> 
     </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

We have to define two attributes '**parallel**' and '**thread-count**' in simple testng.xml file. See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel Execution suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Regression 2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.parallel.TestParallelExecution"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

In above, as we want the test methods to be executed parallel, we have set the parallel attribute as 'methods' and thread-count attribute will control the max number of threads to be created.

Re-installing TestNG solved the above problem.

Comment: Hi Amith, Yes earlier i am using the below .xml file. let me know if i need to modify that .
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parallel" parallel="tests" thread-count="4" >
<test verbose="3" name="<name>">
<parameter name="platform" value ="win8"/>
<parameter name="browsername" value ="internet explorer"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.parallel.execution.ParallelExecution">
      <methods>
  <include name="testmethod1"/>
 </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>

Comment: Yes,it is wrong,you have written only 1 test in this suite,and you are setting parallel='tests', which will always run this single test defined by <test></test> in single thread. Either change the parallel attribute value or write multiple tests in this suite to execute in parallel.

Comment: I have added multiple tests in the suite with different browser, But still browser is invoking one after another and even i have changed the parallel ="methods"

Comment: Use this link: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/parallel-execution-in-selenium-grid, it will give you an idea. Let me kow if still you are not ale to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Actually the testNG which i have installed is not supported . So i re installed the old version of testNG. Now the browsers are invoked in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly write code to invoke the browser as part of a `@Before` configuration to invoke the browser every time a @Test is run . I will specify one of the many approaches so that you get an idea.

```
<suite name="Parallel" parallel="tests" thread-count="4" > 
    <test verbose="3" name="test1"> 
        <classes> 
            <class name="com.parallel.execution.ParallelExecution1"/>  
         </classes> 
    </test> 
    <test verbose="3" name="test2"> 
        <classes> 
            <class name="com.parallel.execution.ParallelExecution2"/>  
        </classes> 
     </test> 
</suite>
```

Consider a suite file with 2 `tests` set to run in parallel. What we expect is `@Test` methods in ParallelExecution1 runs in first browser and `@Test` methods in ParallelExecution2 runs in second browser. So you need a mechanism by which you can invoke browser sessions and run your test methods. Enter `BaseTest` class.

```
public abstract class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;        

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"browser"}) 
    public void init(String browser) {
        // Initialize your browser here. Code below is dummy
        driver = new FF();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void end() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Now inherit this 'BaseTest' in both your test classes.

```
public class ParallelExecution1 extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() { 
    }
}


public class ParallelExecution2 extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test2() { 
    }
}
```

Now both the tests have `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` methods which will invoke the browsers.